# figure numbering (via `\ref{fig-label-name}`) when using user defined `myCaption`

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, numbering, captions

I want to change the font of `Figure`, and the caption text.

I tried `caption` package. But `\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=it]{caption}` raises an error `Command \caption@ContinuedFloat already defined.`.

Then I just define my quick-and-dirty `\myCaption`: `\newcommand{\myCaption}[1]{\textbf{\caption{\textnormal{\textit{#1}}}}}`.

But I notice that the figure numbering (via `\ref`) is sort like section numbering rather than the number after `Figure`.

**EDIT** add an example, it raises the error `! LaTeX Error: Command \caption@ContinuedFloat already defined`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

%%%%%% other packages in my doc %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amssymb, amstext, amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % only 4 figure caroleError

%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

% for landscape figure
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{minipage}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{docmute}

\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{hliFigure}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{afterpage}

% end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% for this minimum example:
% expand \figure to multi pages
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
 {\par\nobreak\end{center}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=it]{caption}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}\centering
    \subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth{linux_penguin.jpg}}\\
    \subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{linux_penguin.jpg}}\\
    \subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{linux_penguin.jpg}}\\
    \subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{linux_penguin.jpg}}\\
    \caption{many figures}
    \label{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm only aware of a single situation causing the error `Command \caption@ContinuedFloat already defined`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

This is happening here: The `subfig` package is loaded with option `caption=false` which means "No, I really don't want to use the caption package". Afterwards the `caption` package is loaded, causing the error since the `subfig` package has already defined some commands which are necessary for sub-figure support without `caption` package.

The solution is simple: Please decide if you want to use the `caption` package, yes or no. (And especially not "no and yes", as stated in my example document.)

And now to Part 2, the "section numbering rather than the number after Figure" problem:

`\label` must be placed within the same group as `\caption`, so `{\caption{...}}\label{...}` fails. But this is what you do inside your definition of `\myCaption`, the `\caption` command is typeset inside `\textbf{...}` while the `\label` is not. Therefore `\ref` is doomed to fail here, giving you the reference to the last labeling command (e.g. `\section`) instead.